# × TypeError: post.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
    import axios from "axios";
    
    
    
    const View = () => {
        const [post, setPost] = useState('');
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getallposts();
      }, []);
    
      //api calling function:
        const getallposts = () => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/posts")
          .then((res) => {
            const allPosts = res.data.posts;        
            setPost(allPosts);
          }
          ).catch((error) => console.log("Error 404"))
      }
    
        console.log(post);
    
        return (
            <Table className="striped bordered hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>fullname</th>
                        <th>phone</th>
                        <th>email</th>
                        <th>msg</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                         post.map((posts) =>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>{posts.fullname}</td>
                                 <td>{posts.phone}</td>
                                 <td>{posts.email}</td>
                                 <td>{posts.msg}</td>
                            </tr>)
                    }
                        )
                        </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    }
    
    export default View;
```

It will continuously showing this error that TypeError: post.map is not a function

and also add some reference to understand map method of javascript if possible

Edit:

My error solved just by putting array[] in const [post, setPost] = useState(''); instead of ''(empty string).
but still what i want as an output is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below code it worked:

```
    const [arrayVal, setArrayVal] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        //API call
        setArrayVal([{a:"a"},{b:"b"])
    },[])
    return (
         arrayVal && arrayVal.map((item) => {
             console.log(item);
         });
    );
```

Please check your value of allPosts if its array or not?

Comment: Try with above code if API returns undefined then also it will not break

Comment: do JSON.parse or JSON.stringify

Comment: Is it coming now? try printing post value in console

Comment: yup i tried to console my value in console log but it gives an error

Comment: try without map
what is the value of POST 
console.log(post)

Comment: now the error of map is gone but it shows nothing now

Comment: try without map what is the value of POST console.log(post), can you post the value of console

Comment: and tried both json.parse & json.stringify but it didn't work.

Comment: any other solutions please

Comment: try without map what is the value of POST console.log(post), can you post the value of console, I want to see the value of post

Comment: (32) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]  yes it works it gives me my array object BUT BUT it gives me this Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: post.map((posts) =>
 <tr>
<td key={posts.id}>{posts.fullname}</td>   <td key={posts.id}>{posts.phone}</td>              <td key={posts.id}>{posts.email}</td>
<td key={posts.id}>{posts.msg}</td>
                        </tr>)
                } when i give unique key as id it gives me  Warning:-   Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: add key <tr> and add some unique value warning will be gone
and its working g8
You can accept my answer

Comment: post.map((posts) =>
                         -----<tr key={posts.id}>----
                             <td>{posts.fullname}</td>
                             <td>{posts.phone}</td>
                             <td>{posts.email}</td>
                             <td>{posts.msg}</td>
                        </tr>)        I did changes according to you still displays nothing  Any other solution  ?

Comment: I said console.log displays an array but actual output is still not visible\

Comment: Try using Json.parse

Comment: and tried both json.parse & json.stringify but it didn't work.  actually i told you this before check previous comments

Answer (score -1):

Change post to array.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined  :-   Now showing this.

Comment: that means the api return undefined. try add a if array check before setPost.

Comment: ok i'll get back to you after trying this

Comment: please clear this that why api returned undefined is there any mistake in calling an api  ??

Comment: I need to see how the api is written to know if there is a mistake in calling, but that is not relavent to what is discussing here. Maybe you want to post another question.

Comment: i mentioned my api calling in the above code by commenting it out

Comment: what is the value of console.log(res.data)?

Comment: yes it will display my array in console but didn't show any output though